# Python shallow copy and deep copy in using append method

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, deep-copy

Some problems come out when using append method in python3.5. The code is presented

```
# generate boson basis in lexicographic order
def boson_basis(L,N):
basis=[]
state=[0 for i in range(1,L+1)]
pos=0
# initialize the state to |N,0,...,0>
state[0]=N
basis.append(state)
# find the first non-zero position in reverse order
while state[L-1]<N:
    for i in range(-2,-L-1,-1):
        if state[i]>0:
            pos=L+i
            break
    sum=0
    for i in range(0,pos):
        sum=sum+state[i]
    state[pos]=state[pos]-1
    state[pos+1]=N-sum-state[pos]
    basis.append(state)
return basis        

result=boson_basis(3,3)
```

the expected result should be `[[3,0,0],[2,1,0],...,[0,0,3]]`, but this code generates wrong results with all elements are the same as the last one, i.e. `[[0,0,3],...,[0,0,3]]`. I use the pdb to debug it and I find that once the `state` is modified, the former `state` that has been appended into `basis` is also changed simultaneously. It implies that `append` uses `deepcopy` automatically which is beyond my understanding. In fact, this error can be fixed if we use `basis(state.copy())` explicitly.

On the other hand, the following simple code shows no error in using `append`

```
x=3
b=[]
b.append(x)
x=x+2
```

after `x` is changed to `x=5`, `b` remains unchanged `b=[3]`. It really puzzles me and seems contradictory with the former example.

Comment: Read up on immutable vs mutable objects, and pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference

Comment: Append does not copy anything, that's why you end up having the same list several times in your list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As revealed in the comments already, there's no copy whatsoever involved in an `append` operation.
So you'll have to explicitly take care of this yourself, e.g. by replacing

```
basis.append(state)
```

with

```
basis.append(state[:])
```

The slicing operation with `:` creates a copy of `state`.
Mind: it does not copy the lists elements - which as long as you're keeping only plain numbers and not objects in your list should be fine though.